# Posix shared memory between parent and child process?

Tags: c, posix

I am writing a program to solve a exercise on the **Operating System Concept** book. That problem is create a Collatz conjecture on child process and print it back the parent process using Posix shared memeory. Here is my program.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
const char* name = "Collatz";
const int SIZE = 4096 * 30;
void *ptr;
int shm_fd;
int num = atoi(argv[1]);
pid_t pid;

shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
ftruncate(shm_fd, SIZE);
ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
if (ptr < 0) perror("Ptr error");
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0) perror("Fork Failed");
else if (pid == 0) {
    shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR, 0666);
    ptr = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    if (ptr < 0) perror("Ptr error");
    while (num != 1) {
        sprintf(ptr, "%d", num);
        ptr++;
        if (num % 2 == 0) num /= 2;
        else num = 3 * num + 1;
    }
    sprintf(ptr, "%d", num);
    ptr++;
} else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("Parent: %s\n", (char*) ptr);

    //ptr += sizeof(int);
    shm_unlink(name);
}
return 0;
}
```

But when I complie it with **gcc**, I got **Segmentation fault(Core dump)**. I have no idea with it though search through Google. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Can someone help me with it. Thank you very much and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You get segfault when compiling?? Not when running?

Comment: If you are using gcc then you should also be using gdb.

Comment: Poor me, I am not pass an integer argument.

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. One thing I noticed above is that you don't include a single header, which can cause various issues.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to compile your code with the following includes and it worked for me.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
```

Have you thought to pass an integer argument when executing the programm ?
(e.g)

```
./collatz 12
```

output 1631518421

Comment: Also, at line 22 you should probably compute the length of the string representing the computed value and increment ptr of this length instead of 1. This way numbers with more than one digit will not be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I hope it will help you. The shared memory is loaded behind the process with the system function mmap(2).

`void ∗ mmap (void ∗ addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);`

The parameters are:
   • addr - address to be loaded into process (usually here we use 0 to let the kernel decide where to load)
   • len- size of memory loaded • prot- access rights (PROTREAD or PROTWRITE usually)
 
   • flags - memory type (usually MAPSHARED so that the changes made by the process wil be visible to the others)
   • fd - the descriptor of the memory object
   • offset - the place in the shared memory object and from which it will be replayed.
    When executed successfully, the result is a pointer to the address in the process space to which the object was loaded. Otherwise, the MAPFAILED value is returned and errno is set to the appropriate value.
    Pay attetion that in Linux the size must be a multiple of pages: PAGE_SIZE (for this I used getpagesize(2) )

```cpp
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <sys/sysmacros.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Starting parent %d\n", getpid());

        int wstatus, shm_fd;
        char shm_name[] = "collatz";
        struct stat sb;
        pid_t pid;
        unsigned int displacement = 0,  offset = 0;
        size_t shm_size = getpagesize() * (argc - 1);

        if(argc < 2)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "At least one argument must be passed!");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        int *pid_children = (int*)malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(int));
        if(pid_children == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Create shared memory object */
        shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if(shm_fd < 0)
        {
            perror(NULL);
            return errno;
        }

        /* Define size */
        if(ftruncate(shm_fd, shm_size) == -1) {
            perror(NULL);
            shm_unlink(shm_name);
            return errno;
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
        {
            int n = atoi(argv[i]), aux = atoi(argv[i]);
            if(n < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Only positive numbers!\n");
                i = i + 1;
            }

            pid_children[i - 1] = fork();
            if(pid_children[i - 1] < 0)
                return errno;
            if(pid_children[i - 1] == 0)
            {
                /* Child instructions */
                char *shm_ptr_child = mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, (i - 1) * getpagesize());
                if(shm_ptr_child == MAP_FAILED)
                {
                    perror(NULL);
                    shm_unlink(shm_name);
                    return errno;
                }

                int count = 0;
                int *series = (int*)malloc(count * sizeof(int));
                if(series == NULL)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error!");
                    exit(1);
                }

                *(series + count) = n;
                while(n != 1)
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    series = (int*)realloc(series, (count + 1) * sizeof(int));
                    if(series ==  NULL)
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failure!");
                        free(series);
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }

                    if(n % 2== 0)
                        n = n / 2;
                    else
                        n = 3 * n + 1;

                    *(series + count) = n;
                }
                if(n == 1){
                    offset = sprintf(shm_ptr_child, "%d : ", aux);
                    shm_ptr_child += offset;
                    for(int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++)
                    {
                        offset = sprintf(shm_ptr_child, "%d ", series[i]);
                        shm_ptr_child += offset;
                    }

                    free(series);
                    munmap(shm_ptr_child, getpagesize());

                    fprintf(stdout, "Done Parent: %d, Me: %d \n", getppid(), getpid());
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                }
                else
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else{
                /* Parent instructions */
                do{
                    pid = waitpid(pid_children[i - 1], &wstatus, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
                    if(pid == -1)
                    {
                        perror("waitpid");
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if(WIFEXITED(wstatus)){
                        fprintf(stdout, "exited, status = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(wstatus));
                    }else if(WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "killed by the signal: %d\n", WTERMSIG(wstatus));
                    }else if(WIFSTOPPED(wstatus)) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "stopped by the signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(wstatus));
                    }else if(WIFCONTINUED(wstatus)) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "continued\n");
                    }

                }while(!WIFEXITED(wstatus) && !WIFSIGNALED(wstatus));

            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
        {
            char *shm_ptr = mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, i * getpagesize());
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", shm_ptr);
            munmap(shm_ptr, getpagesize());
        }
        shm_unlink(shm_name);

        printf("\nDone Parent: %d, Children: %d \n", getppid(), getpid());

        return 0;
}
```